# SQL: Is there a possibility to convert numbers (1,2,3,4...) to letters (A,B,C,D...)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a possibility to obtain letters (like A,B) instead of numbers (1,2) e.g. as a result of  Dense_Rank function call(in MS Sql) ?

Comment: Consider that the problem "translate numbers into letters" is completely separate from "rank these rows" - there's no specific reason why this question is about `dense_rank`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   Letters = Char(64 + T.Num),
   T.Col1,
   T.Col2
FROM
   dbo.YourTable T
;
```

Just be aware that when you get to 27 (past `Z`), things are going to get interesting, and not useful.

If you wanted to start doubling up letters, as in `... X, Y, Z, AA, AB, AC, AD ...` then it's going to get a bit trickier. This works in all versions of SQL Server. The `SELECT` clauses are just an alternate to a CASE statement (and 2 characters shorter, each).

```
SELECT
   *,
   LetterCode =
      Coalesce((SELECT Char(65 + (N.Num - 475255) / 456976 % 26) WHERE N.Num >= 475255), '')
      + Coalesce((SELECT Char(65 + (N.Num - 18279) / 17576 % 26) WHERE N.Num >= 18279), '')
      + Coalesce((SELECT Char(65 + (N.Num - 703) / 676 % 26) WHERE N.Num >= 703), '')
      + Coalesce((SELECT Char(65 + (N.Num - 27) / 26 % 26) WHERE N.Num >= 27), '')
      + (SELECT Char(65 + (N.Num - 1) % 26))
FROM dbo.YourTable N
ORDER BY N.Num
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68b32/256)

(Demo for SQL 2008 and up, note that I use `Dense_Rank()` to simulate a series of numbers)

This will work from `A` to `ZZZZZ`, representing the values `1` to `12356630`. The reason for all the craziness above instead of a more simple expression is because `A` doesn't simply represent `0`, here. Before each threshold when the sequence kicks over to the next letter `A` added to the front, there is in effect a hidden, blank, digit--but it's not used again. So 5 letters long is not 26^5 combinations, it's 26 + 26^2 + 26^3 + 26^4 + 26^5!

It took some REAL tinkering to get this code working right... I hope you or someone appreciates it! This can easily be extended to more letters just by adding another letter-generating expression with the right values.

Since it appears I'm now square in the middle of a proof-of-manliness match, I did some performance testing. A `WHILE` loop is to me not a great way to compare performance because my query is designed to run against an entire set of rows at once. It doesn't make sense to me to run it a million times against one row (basically forcing it into virtual-UDF land) when it can be run once against a million rows, which is the use case scenario given by the OP for performing this against a large rowset. So here's the script to test against 1,000,000 rows (test script requires SQL Server 2005 and up).

```
DECLARE
   @Buffer varchar(16),
   @Start datetime;

SET @Start = GetDate();
WITH A (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) A (N)),
B (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM A, A X),
C (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM B, B X),
D (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM C, B X),
N (Num) AS (SELECT Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM D)
SELECT @Buffer = dbo.HinkyBase26(N.Num)
FROM N
;
SELECT [HABO Elapsed Milliseconds] = DateDiff( ms, @Start, GetDate());

SET @Start = GetDate();
WITH A (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) A (N)),
B (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM A, A X),
C (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM B, B X),
D (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM C, B X),
N (Num) AS (SELECT Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM D)
SELECT
   @Buffer =
      Coalesce((SELECT Char(65 + (N.Num - 475255) / 456976 % 26) WHERE N.Num >= 475255), '')
      + Coalesce((SELECT Char(65 + (N.Num - 18279) / 17576 % 26) WHERE N.Num >= 18279), '')
      + Coalesce((SELECT Char(65 + (N.Num - 703) / 676 % 26) WHERE N.Num >= 703), '')
      + Coalesce((SELECT Char(65 + (N.Num - 27) / 26 % 26) WHERE N.Num >= 27), '')
      + (SELECT Char(65 + (N.Num - 1) % 26))   
FROM N
;
SELECT [ErikE Elapsed Milliseconds] = DateDiff( ms, @Start, GetDate());
```

And the results:

```
UDF: 17093 ms
ErikE: 12056 ms
```

**Original Query**

I initially did this a "fun" way by generating 1 row per letter and pivot-concatenating using XML, but while it was indeed fun, it proved to be slow. Here is that version for posterity (SQL 2005 and up required for the `Dense_Rank`, but will work in SQL 2000 for just converting numbers to letters):

```
WITH Ranks AS (
   SELECT
      Num = Dense_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY T.Sequence),
      T.Col1,
      T.Col2
   FROM
      dbo.YourTable T
)
SELECT
   *,
   LetterCode =
      (
         SELECT Char(65 + (R.Num - X.Low) / X.Div % 26)
         FROM
            (
               SELECT 18279, 475254, 17576
               UNION ALL SELECT 703, 18278, 676
               UNION ALL SELECT 27, 702, 26
               UNION ALL SELECT 1, 26, 1
            ) X (Low, High, Div)      
         WHERE R.Num >= X.Low
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
      ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(4)')
FROM Ranks R
ORDER BY R.Num
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68b32/255)

Comment: What I'm saying is that your expression only works from 26 to 701... an expression that works for 0 - 475253 is what I'm cooking up now.

Comment: @ErikE - Why not create a UDF that takes a `BIGINT` and returns the eccentric base-26 equivalent string?  Just do the usual mod/div shuffle to change bases.  Or use a nice, slow recursive CTE.

Comment: @Erike,  I'm trying the same and its taking longer than I thought... I'll leave it to you...

Comment: @HABO It's very complicated because (say, we want up to `ZZZZ`) you don't start at `AAAA` where `A` represents `0`! You actually have 27 possible digits in some cases and 26 in others for the first 3 digits--since for `A-Z` for example the first three digits are blank, which is an extra value in addition to `A-Z`.

Comment: Got it up to Three letters....

`select case When Dense_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY T.Sequence) < 703 Then ' ' Else
 Char(64 + ((Dense_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY T.Sequence)-26) / 26 / 26)) End +

    case When Dense_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY T.Sequence) < 27 Then ' ' 
      When Dense_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY T.Sequence) < 703 Then 
      Char(64 + ((Dense_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY T.Sequence)-1)/ 26))
 Else Char(65 + ((Dense_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY T.Sequence)-1)% 702 / 26)) End +

    Char(65 + ((Dense_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY T.Sequence) - 1) % 26))  FROM  dbo.YourTable T`

Comment: @CharlesBretana That's not too far from what I was doing, but I got tired of the nasty complicated expressions. I really like the table-valued way I settled on!

Comment: @Erik, substantial complexity was induced by trying to make the first 26 only have one character, and the first 702 only have 2 characters....

Comment: @ErikE - The UDF didn't seem that complex.  Your reference to having a variable number of possible digits (26 or 27) is a bit confusing.  Do you mean that if you left-pad with blanks you consider that to be imaginary digits?  I didn't notice a specific field width in the question and would consider that to be a matter of applying the padding after conversion.

Comment: @HABO I think some performance testing is in order. I avoid multi-statement UDFs like the plague...

Comment: @ErikE - Well, the good news is that I fixed the UDF. That 27/26 thing wasn't handled correctly. Mea culpa. My answer is updated and includes a quick benchmark of the UDF and XML solutions.

Answer (score 7):

hint:   try this in your SQL Enterprise manager

```
  select char(65), char(66), char(67)
```

a full solution, for ranks up to 17,500 (or three letters, up to ZZZ) is:

```
select 
    case When rnk < 703 Then ''
 else Char(64 + ((rnk-26) / 26 / 26)) End +
    case When rnk < 27 Then '' 
   When rnk < 703 Then Char(64 + ((rnk-1)/ 26))
 else Char(65 + ((rnk-1)% 702 / 26)) End +
    Char(65 + ((rnk - 1) % 26))  
from (select Dense_Rank() 
     OVER (ORDER BY T.Sequence) rnk
      From YourTable t) z
```

Answer (score 5):

You can convert the values to an offset base-26 with a UDF:

**EDIT**: Corrected function.

```
create function dbo.HinkyBase26( @Value as BigInt ) returns VarChar(15) as
  begin
  -- Notes: 'A' = 0.  Negative numbers are not handled.
  declare @Result as VarChar(15) = '';

  if @Value = 0
    select @Result = 'A';
  else
    set @Value += 1;
  while @Value > 0
    select @Value -= 1, @Result = Char( ASCII( 'A' ) + @Value % 26 ) + @Result, @Value /= 26;
  return @Result;
  end;
```

Sample values:

```
select Arabic, dbo.HinkyBase26( Arabic ) as Alpha
  from ( values ( 0 ), ( 1 ), ( 25 ), ( 26 ), ( 51 ), ( 52 ),
    ( 27 * 26 - 1 ), ( 27 * 26 ),
    ( 33685567531 ) ) as Foo( Arabic );
```

At ErikE's suggestion I ran a quick performance test on my notebook.  1,000,000 iterations of the UDF vs. the XML solution:

```
declare @Count as Int;
declare @Buffer as VarChar(16);
declare @Start as DateTime;

select @Count = 1000000, @Start = GetDate();
while @Count > 0
  select @Buffer = dbo.HinkyBase26( @Count ), @Count -= 1;
select DateDiff( ms, @Start, GetDate() ) as 'Elapsed Milliseconds'; -- 14,583    
select @Count = 1000000, @Start = GetDate();
while @Count > 0
  select @Buffer =
      (
         SELECT Char( ASCII( 'A' ) + (@Count - X.Low) / X.Div % 26)
         FROM
            (
               SELECT 18279, 475254, 17576
               UNION ALL SELECT 703, 18278, 676
               UNION ALL SELECT 27, 702, 26
               UNION ALL SELECT 1, 26, 1
            ) X (Low, High, Div)      
         WHERE @Count >= X.Low
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
      ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(4)'), @Count -= 1;
select DateDiff( ms, @Start, GetDate() ) as 'Elapsed Milliseconds'; -- 47,256
```

The UDF was a little more than 3 times faster.

---

Going the *other* way would be something like:

```
create function dbo.DehinkyBase26( @Value as VarChar(15) ) returns BigInt as
  begin
  -- Notes: 'A' = 0.  Negative numbers are not handled.
  declare @Result as BigInt = -1;

  while @Value > ''
    select @Result = ASCII( Left( @Value, 1 ) ) - ASCII( 'A' ) + ( @Result + 1 ) * 26,
      @Value = Right( @Value, Len( @Value ) - 1 );
  return @Result;
  end;
```

and:

```
select Arabic, dbo.HinkyBase26( Arabic ) as Alpha,
  dbo.DehinkyBase26( dbo.HinkyBase26( Arabic ) ) as RoundTrip
  from ( values ( 0 ), ( 1 ), ( 25 ), ( 26 ), ( 51 ), ( 52 ),
    ( 27 * 26 - 1 ), ( 27 * 26 ),
    ( 33685567531 ) ) as Foo( Arabic );
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LImrsX3a).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaw in using XML--I confess a big part of my solution was really  about playing with shiny toys. I have now buckled down and produced the solution I should have in the first place. Please see my answer for new results, UDF 17093ms, my query 12056ms. (If you get to update your code after making loud "it was EASY" and "there IS no 26/27 thing" noises, then I get to update my code, too!) P.S. my old query stopped @ <1 million. And, taking a row-based solution and turning it into a virtual UDF by running it over and over in a `WHILE` loop is in my mind not a good test.

Comment: @HABO - Can we get it in reverse as well? if we input the returned ALPHABET value need the number

Comment: @user1720827 Sure, you could throw together something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/LImrsX3a), but that would be the answer to a different question.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer - but if somebody has a alphabet conversion requirement with 3 characters, following is what I am doing.

```
/*                    
Function Desc: Convert integer value to 3 character alpha-numeric
--Note: 1. This will return unique values from 0 to 17575, after that it startes again from AAA.
        2. Returns NULL If less than 0.

--Test Values
    select dbo.udfGetBase26CharacterValue(0) --AAA
    select dbo.udfGetBase26CharacterValue(17575) --ZZZ
    select dbo.udfGetBase26CharacterValue(17576) --AAA
    select dbo.udfGetBase26CharacterValue(NULL) --NULL
    select dbo.udfGetBase26CharacterValue(-1) --NULL
*/


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].udfGetBase26CharacterValue
(    
    @id INT
)    
RETURNS CHAR(3)   
AS    
BEGIN    

IF ((@id < 0) OR (@id IS NULL))
BEGIN
    Return NULL
END

--Convert to base 26
Return  char(@id / power(26,2) % 26 + 65) +
            char(@id / 26 % 26 + 65) + 
            char(@id % 26 + 65)    

END
```

Another approach - get next character code (it is alpha-numeric result). If you pass '00A' it will return '00B'

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetNextCharacterCode (@InputCode char(3))
RETURNS char(3)
AS
BEGIN


IF LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@InputCode))) = 2
BEGIN
    SET @InputCode = '0'+LTRIM(RTRIM(@InputCode))
END
ELSE IF LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@InputCode))) = 1
BEGIN
    SET @InputCode = '00'+LTRIM(RTRIM(@InputCode))
END


DECLARE @NewCode char(3)

SELECT @NewCode =
                    CASE WHEN RIGHT(@InputCode,2) != 'ZZ' THEN LEFT(@InputCode,1)
                       ELSE CHAR(
                                    CASE LEFT(@InputCode,1) WHEN '9' THEN 64 
                                                       WHEN 'Z' THEN 47 
                                                       ELSE ASCII(LEFT(@InputCode,1)
                                            ) 
                                  END + 1
                                )
                 END ---First Char
                 + 
                 CASE WHEN RIGHT(@InputCode,1) != 'Z' THEN SUBSTRING(@InputCode,2,1)
                       ELSE CHAR(
                                    CASE SUBSTRING(@InputCode,2,1) WHEN '9' THEN 64 
                                                       WHEN 'Z' THEN 47 
                                                       ELSE ASCII(SUBSTRING(@InputCode,2,1)) 
                                    END + 1
                                )
                   END ---Second Char
                + 
                CHAR(CASE RIGHT(@InputCode,1) WHEN '9' THEN 64 
                                         WHEN 'Z' THEN 47 
                                         ELSE ASCII(RIGHT(@InputCode,1)) 
                        END + 1) ---Third Char

RETURN @NewCode
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this as a basis for my function to convert integers to base26 character strings

```
DECLARE @Input integer  = 3000

DECLARE @Value     integer  
DECLARE @Quotient  integer      = 0
DECLARE @Remainder integer      = 0
DECLARE @Output    varchar(max) = ''

DECLARE @BASE char(26) = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

SET @Value = @Input

WHILE @Value > 0 BEGIN

  SET @Quotient  = @Value / 26
  SET @Remainder = @Value % 26

  SET @Output = substring(@BASE,@Remainder,1) + @Output

  SELECT @Value = @Quotient

END

SELECT @Output --- DKJ
```