# How to convert an ordinal to Excel A1 notation in TSQL

Tags: excel, t-sql

Using T-SQL how do I convert an ordinal column position number to an Excel A1 notation column reference?

eg:

```
1  => A
2  => B
...
26 => Z
27 => AA
28 => AB
...
52 => AZ
```

and so forth.

The background is we have a complicated CSV file generated from an MS-SQL view. The CSV is generated without headers. I want to generate some documentation for a support user which maps the column position to the column name as it would import into Excel.

Comment: doh. should have searched harder the first time - thanks @HABO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer was buggy. Updated with a functionalised version of the answer from `charles-bretana` that this Q/A turned out to be a duplicate of.

```
-- Based off http://stackoverflow.com/a/16995299/1141876
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.OrdinalToExcelA1
(
    @value      INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10) AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(10)

   select @Output =
                    CASE 
                        WHEN @value < 703 THEN ''
                        ELSE CHAR(64 + ((@value-26) / 26 / 26)) 
                    END 
                    +
                    CASE 
                        WHEN @value < 27 THEN '' 
                        WHEN @value < 703 Then Char(64 + ((@value-1)/ 26))
                        ELSE CHAR(65 + ((@value-1)% 702 / 26)) 
                    END 
                    +
                    CHAR(65 + ((@value - 1) % 26))  

    RETURN @Output
END
GO
```

Here is the code to test

```
;WITH Nums AS
(
  SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_objects 

)
select n AS ColumnOrdinal, dbo.OrdinalToExcelA1(n) as ExcelA1Format
FROM Nums 
WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND 100
ORDER BY n;
```

and here is how to use it

```
SELECT  dbo.OrdinalToExcelA1(ORDINAL_POSITION)  AS ExcelColumn
        ,Column_Name                            AS Name
FROM    information_schema.columns 
WHERE   table_name = 'MY-VIEW-NAME'
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.