# Add Alphabet column in select statement

Tags: sql-server

I want to add alphabet column when we get write a select query

my query is: -

```
select empname, address from Employee table
```

I want to get data like

```
empname address alphabetcolumn
Pramod  USA       A
xyz     USA       B
```

Comment: Could do with a more fleshed out example. I presume you want to assign 26 letters in A-Z order to (up to) the first 26 rows. What happens if there are more that 26 rows?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever after 26 row lie AA, AB etc

Comment: The question is rather vague. What does `alphabet column` mean and where would those letters come from? Why should `Pramod` have an `A` but `xyz` have a `B`? Is this an attempt to number the columns using letters?

Comment: @PramodGehlot I suggest improving the question with what you actually want, and *why*. Using letters to number columns is unusual at best and would result in a bizzare sorting sequence. `AA` would come before `Z` for example

Comment: Can you explain the reason for this requirement? Seems a little odd, and it's not so simple to do. Also, do you need this stored on the table or it can be calculated on a report select?

Comment: A `column` is a definition of a piece of data stored in the table, in a query its just a computed part of the `resultset`.

Comment: @PramodGehlot it is far easier to generate such sequences in a report tool. If you want ranking, you can use one of the ranking functions

Comment: @PramodGehlot you can create a [Numbers table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained--part-1/) with extra columns that map numbers to text, eg 1 to A, 2 to B, 27 to whatever you pick and join the results of `ROW_NUMBER()` with that table to get the string you want. You'll have to fill that table only once with as many numbers as you want. Even with 1M rows the table will take very little space (12 MB for just the numbers)

Comment: Possible Duplicate [SQL: Is there a possibility to convert numbers (1,2,3,4…) to letters (A,B,C,D…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995265/sql-is-there-a-possibility-to-convert-numbers-1-2-3-4-to-letters-a-b-c-d)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Is there a possibility to convert numbers (1,2,3,4...) to letters (A,B,C,D...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995265/sql-is-there-a-possibility-to-convert-numbers-1-2-3-4-to-letters-a-b-c-d)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below approach.

in ASCII table `A` starts from 65.  `ROW_NUMBER` starts from 1. Hence, I am summing row_number with 64 to get 65+.

```
select 
  empname, 
  address,
  CHAR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY empname ASC)) + 64) AS ALPHABET
from Employee
```

with two characters support you can use this approach

```
With r as 
(  
   select 
     empname, 
     address,
     CHAR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY empname ASC)) + 64) AS rn
   from Employee
)
select IIF(rn / 26 = 0, '', char(rn/26 + 64)) + char((rn -1) % 26 +65)  
from r;
```

Comment: @simonare what we will do after 26 row

Comment: @PramodGehlot you never asked for more than 26 rows. *Update the question*

Answer (score 0):

I get the idea that this *isn't* what the OP is after, but based on the limited information.

You can add a new column to your table by using:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD alphabetcolumn char(1);
```

Comment: I have not add column i want to select time add column

Comment: @PramodGehlot that's not what you wrote in the question. This answer is correct given the lack of information

Comment: The time add column, @PramodGehlot ?There is no "`timeadd`" column in your question. Where does that even come from?

Comment: @Larnu from a comment in the question which explains that the OP wants ranking, not a column at all